# Are there network-wide reputation leagues?

Tags: feature-request, support, reputation, reputation-leagues, top-users

I would love to see which people have the **most network-wide reputation**, how can I see that?

Comment: I'd venture that [John Skeet wins - 474,000](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=accounts) .  nice idea ! This should be a straight-forward feature to do.

Comment: Having both an all-time one, which obviously Jon would win, and the usual weekly, monthly and quarterly ones would be interesting.

Comment: No it would not be that interesting; the SO question rate makes it *much* easier to gain rep there, so the network-wide league woud be dominated by the SO crowd, hands-down.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Any statistics to back this statement up? As question rate goes up, answer rate goes up as well so it might not be as easy to get a few upvoted answers as you think. Hands-up, SO is well-known for its FGITW problem... ;)

Comment: If you compare [Stack Overflow leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) with [Mathematics](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/week/math) (second most active site in the network), you'll see, week-after-week that the weekly scores are almost always higher on SO.

Comment: @mar statistics are still valid. 2 years later.

Answer (score 6):

Although a feature like this sounds very cool and could be implemented without much effort (I think), I do wonder what will be the usefulness of it.

Reputation among sites isn't exchangeable. The ratio on answers and up-votes differ a lot among sites. Also on some sites people are more willing to vote than others.

We do not want people to 'bet' on that other site because it has a higher ratio than the lower traffic, less popular site, which could use some hands.

Some figures, going on [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140890/martijn-pieters)' comment:

Take the current years reputation (so from Jan 2015 until Aug 2015) of the highest scoring users on [Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2015-01-01?sort=reputationchange) and [Mathematics](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/year/math/2015-01-01?sort=reputationchange) (second most active site in the network): SO 70K, Mathematics 46K. And the top user in [Seasoned Advice](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/11/year/cooking/2015-01-01?sort=reputationchange) has an astonishing 7K! There is no way for a user in Seasoned Advice or even in Mathematics to come close to the SO user. No matter how much they try.

I think that the side effects of this feature must be thought of first. Then we should see the nice feature.

Comment: You might consider updating the numbers... the highest rep user on Seasoned advice has over 50 K now. Regardless, it sounded like the question is asking for total rep on all sites. I may only have 5 K on any one site but between all of my sites, that's 16K or so... which is still pitifully small but *shrug*.

Comment: @Catija the numbers are updated. It is the rep of the current year, not the grand total since every site has another start date. Seems unfair to compare.

Comment: [TeX](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/29/year/tex/2015-01-01?sort=reputationchange) has someone with 55k this year, by the by.

Comment: that is getting closer to SO already. Still not close to Seasoned Advice... @nat

Comment: @PatrickHofman  Ah, sorry I missed that, not enough coffee I guess